# MySQL Median Inner Join

Tags: mysql, join, median

I'm trying to figure out where to put the following `INNER JOIN` statement:

```
INNER JOIN resort_blocked_task ON d.task_id = resort_blocked_task.blocked_task_fbid
```

Into this MySQL statement:

```
SELECT sq.team_id, avg(sq.time_owned) as median_val FROM (
SELECT t1.row_number, t1.time_owned, t1.team_id FROM(
SELECT IF(@prev!=d.team_id, @rownum:=1, @rownum:=@rownum+1) as `row_number`, d.time_owned, @prev:=d.team_id AS team_id, d.task_id
FROM task_timer d, (SELECT @rownum:=0, @prev:=NULL) r
ORDER BY team_id, time_owned
) as t1 INNER JOIN  
(
  SELECT count(*) as total_rows, team_id 
  FROM task_timer d
  GROUP BY team_id
) as t2
ON t1.team_id = t2.team_id
WHERE 1=1
AND t1.row_number>=t2.total_rows/2 and t1.row_number<=t2.total_rows/2+1
)sq
group by sq.team_id
```

No matter where I'm trying to put the INNER JOIN too many results are being filtered out causing the median to be incorrect.

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c9ab/2/0) of some example data.

Comment: What do you need from the resort_blocked_task table? Would a left join or exists check work? In fact, what are you after in general?

Comment: @GarethLyons I'm trying to obtain the median time a blocked task is owned for grouped by team_id. I don't think a left join would work because I only want data on blocked tasks.

Comment: thanks, so in your example what is being filtered out that shouldn't be? I can't see a problem with it at the moment.

Comment: I am not sure where to add the INNER JOIN statement at the beginning of my post. No matter where I seem to add it, too many results get filtered out.